# Show that from following equivalence we get homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

I have given X and Y topological spaces and f is a bijective function. I have to show that from B $\subseteq X$ : f(B) closed in Y $\iff $ B is closed in X it follows that f an Homeomorphism is.

I am struggling with this and I really would appreciate your help

Comment: Do you know that a function is continuous iff inverse images of closed sets are closed?

Answer (score 0):

Well, by definition, a function $g : X \to Y$ is continuous if for any open set $U \subseteq Y$, the set $g^{-1}(U)$ is open in X.

Now, for $f$ to be a homeomorphism, you want both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ to be continuous... can you see where this is going? :)